# Parameterized nested query

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to parameterize the following insert with a nested select.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table1 (creation_timestamp, str1, str2) 
    (SELECT now(), "param1", str2 FROM table2 WHERE key = "param2");
```

I'd like something like

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table1 (creation_timestamp, str1, str2) 
    (SELECT now(), ?, str2 FROM table2 WHERE key = ?) 
    VALUES ("param1", "param2");
```

Anyone know how I can accomplish something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly the same, but very similar.

You can use prepared statements:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

**Example:**

```
PREPARE soExample 
FROM 'INSERT 
      INTO usr (id, username, profile_pic) 
      VALUES (NULL, ?, (SELECT name 
                        FROM customers 
                        WHERE id = ? 
                        LIMIT 1))';

SET @uname = "someUserNameForTheExample";
SET @id = "1";
EXECUTE soExample USING @uname, @id;
```

Or you can user procedure or/and functions as well

**FUNCTION**

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS insertExample$$
CREATE FUNCTION insertExample(userNameVar VARCHAR(255), uID INT(11)) RETURNS BOOLEAN
BEGIN
    INSERT 
    INTO usr (id, username, profile_pic) 
    VALUES (NULL, userNameVar, (SELECT name 
                                FROM customers 
                                WHERE id = uID 
                                LIMIT 1));
    IF ROW_COUNT() > 0 THEN 
        RETURN TRUE;
    ELSE
        RETURN FALSE;
    END IF;                
END$$
```

**FUNCTION USE**

```
SELECT insertExample("SomeUsername" 2);
```

Comment: Thanks, like I mentioned in @Tezla 's answer, I'm confined to keeping the queries inside the code (java), so functions/procs are unavailable to me. I also have the inconvenience of having to go through Vert.x for my SQL calls, so I'm not sure if I can use prepared statements as such, but I'm looking into it. Thanks.

Comment: As I feared, it looks like the Vert.x 2 mysql mod is extremely limited. https://github.com/timyates/mod-jdbc-persistor - Just basic queries. I don't see a way to use prepared statements, even when the mod is using them under the hood. I'm afraid I'm stuck with tiny chained queries for the moment, until I can convince the powers that be to let me tear out this Vert.x crap. It's fine for front end REST calls, but it has been nothing but a headache for back end work.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should start by reading https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html. As Mysql Functions enables parameterized input for pre-build queries.

Comment: I'd love to used stored functions/procs, but my hands are tied for the time being. I have to keep the query logic out of the DB.

Comment: look at @VelkoGeorgiev answer, it's well explained.